# Subversion: mark as merged without changing anything

Tags: svn, merge

We have a large project in SVN, including code and a sub-module for documentation.

When merging between the different versions, naturally the code changes need to be merged. But, the eligible revisions also always contain the docs as being eligible for merging. This is annoying, as changes to the docs can't really be "merged" the same was as code - changes to the docs are done manually on the different branches.

Is there a way to have SVN mark the docs as having been merged, without actually changing the content of any files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what the [`--record-only` flag](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.ref.svn.html#svn.ref.svn.sw.record_only) is meant for:

> `--record-only`
>
> Enables a special mode of svn merge in which the specified merge operation is recorded in the local merge tracking information, but is
>   not actually performed.